# E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

Tags: debian, kali-linux

Am new to linux and I have been struggling with the above error for a week now. The solutions am seeing are not working. How do I solve this please. `E: The value 'stable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

I always get the error whenever I try to download packages. like visual studio code `

am using Kali Linux(Kali GNU/Linux Rolling).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need set stable version you just follow the apt command for install.